# PHP - Get random image from xml file

Tags: php, xml, image, random, rss

I want to display a random image from the Unsplash.com RSS feed (https://unsplash.com/rss) using PHP. I've read about how to this, but I can't seem to quite understand it. I think the easiest way to do this is would be with SimpleXML. Then I'd like to use the image as a background-image for my website. Can anyone help me out with this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
function getRandomImageFromRSS($url = 'https://unsplash.com/rss')
{
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

    $images = array();
    foreach ($xml->channel->item as $item) 
    {
        foreach ($item->image->url as $url) 
        {
            $images[] = (string) $url;
        }
    }

    shuffle($images);

    return isset($images[0]) ? $images[0] : null;
}

echo getRandomImageFromRSS();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Worked like a charm!